# Is it possible to thread paginated Google Drive API requests?

Tags: python, google-drive-api

I am able to use the Google Drive v3 API to get a list of files using service.files().list() and can use service.files().list_next() to get paginated results.   I have a use case where I need to search an entire Google Drive and that can sometimes be 50,000+ files and even at the max page size of 1000 that can take several minutes or more.

I am wondering if it is possible(with python) to thread the requests so that I can, for example, request 10 pages at a time?  From reading the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/resources/api-libraries/documentation/drive/v3/python/latest/drive_v3.files.html#list) it seems that the requests must be sent sequentially as the response from request #1 is required in order to send request #2.  Does anyone know if there is a way around that?

Comment: What about starting different `list` requests with discreet search criteria? (eg. contains A,B,..Z [26 requests], not contains A-Z [1 request]; or by modification dates, etc.)